# Adding a new computer's ssh key to a server

Tags: ssh

I have a server that currently accepts passwordless ssh login on my desktop computer. Now I want to log into the server using my laptop. If I didn't have access to my desktop computer, how would I be able to add my laptops ssh key? In fact every time I try to ssh into the server from my laptop, it asks me for the password. I'm not sure what this is asking for, what password is it referring to? None of the passwords that I know works, it's always giving back permission denied. Is it the private ssh key I setup from my desktop computer?

Basically, how would I login to the server from the laptop?

This is on a digital ocean server. I changed the sshd_config file and allowed by uncommenting:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Apparently both of the above were commented out even when my passwordless ssh worked from the desktop computer. How could this happen?

I know I can do ssh-copy-id, but doesn't that require me to be able to SSH into the server in the first place? With no access to the desktop workstation, there's no way to access the server in any way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Anyway:

- When you login to a server, you are asked the password of the *remote* user on that server. This user is usually specified when doing ssh:

  ```
  ssh remote_user@server
  ```
- However, it is possible to login without a password or with a passphrase (i.e., a password on the local PC used to encrypt the real ssh password). This is well explained [here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html). In practice, a ssh password is stored on your local computer and used to automatically connect to the remote server. This password is encrypted and can be protected by a passphrase.

Comment: I see, so I'm trying to get the remote_user's password. In this case it's root. So how do I know what the root's password is?

Comment: I think I'll have to reset the root password.